# How to not allow the user to touch the Form1 While Form2 is opened

Tags: c#, winforms

Is possible to do `not allow` the user to click on the `Form1` while `Form2` is opened?

e.g.: I Debug my application, and it opens my MainForm `Form1`.
There's a button that opens `Form2`, but the user still able to minimize the `Form` and interact with the `Form1`. How may I cut this out ?

Comment: You could just hide `Form1` when `Form2` is open.

Comment: But this way won't compromise the performance?

Comment: @Ghaleon The performance shouldn't be a problem with either solution.

Comment: `Form1` would still be alive, it just won't be visible. I assume it'd have the same performance impact that the answers given would have. But I'd go with Servy's answer. He's good like that.

Comment: Great ! Thank you. Yeah, he already saved me once ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `Form2` using [`ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx):

```
new Form2().ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `ShowDialog()` rather than `Show()` to show the second form.

Comment: Sorry for ask that, I know it's out of topic. But are you the same Servy FROM msdn ? :D

Answer (score 0):

Of course using `ShowDialog` seems to be the best. You can use this code to achieve what you want in another way:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1(){
       InitializeComponent();           
       Button button = new Button() {Text = "Show Form2"};
       button.Click += (s,e) => {
           f = new Form2();
           f.Show();
       };
       button.Parent = this;        
    }
    private Form f;
    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e){
       if(f!=null&&f.Visible) f.BringToFront();
    }
}
```